# tasks.map is not a function

Tags: react

Não estou conseguindo executar o programa.
Aparece a seguinte erro ao clicar em adicionar.
task.map is not a function

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
import React, { useState } from "react"


export default function App() {

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    "Pagar a conta de luz",
    "Estudar React Hooks"]);

  const [input, setInput] = useState("")

  function handleAdd() {
    setTasks(...tasks, input)
    setInput("")
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {tasks.map((task) => (
          <li key={task}>{task}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <input type="text" value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>Adicionar</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Se a ideia é adicionar `input` no array, a linha `setTasks(...tasks, input)` está errada. Deveria ser `setTasks([...tasks, input])`, com os colchetes